# how to execute the code by pressing the button? JSP

Tags: java, jsp, button

I have jsp page and html form with button on this. How execute java code by pressing the button if this code writen on this jsp page?

Comment: what exactly you want? and http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, when the user press a button , it is in the front end , not the back end ,so when the user press the button , it should invoke a request through the http protocol , when the server accept this request , it can call your java code ,but I don't think you can do in your way!

Comment: Im ask wrong question. How about this. I have a button on jsp page. Click this button call JS function. If i write Java code in this JS function this will execute?                                           Im asking couse my tomcat often does not deploy projects. SO i want do this with small number of attempts.

Comment: PS i know my english is terrible/

Comment: Just install Tomcat in your local environment? Then you can (hot)deploy as often as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to execute any java code within the browser.  JavaScript, yes, but not Java.  If you need to call back to your java code, set up a servlet or another JSP (or something better if you're using a web framework) and have your JavaScript call back to that servlet using an `XMLHttpRequest` object (eg. Ajax / Asynchronous JavaScript and XML).

There's lots of info out on the web to help you get started with this.  Also you can use JavaScript frameworks that will help simplify the client side for you.  Popular examples include jQuery, Mootools, Prototype, and many more.